# nohup in sh script not working

Tags: java, shell, quartz-scheduler, nohup

I'm having a problem with a sh script. I'm working on a sh script that allows me to execute a java script in background, and before executing it, check if it is currently running.

The code is here:

```
## START ##
start)
echo $" "
echo $"Checking for agents running, wait please..."
MI_PS=$(ps -ef|grep $JAR_NAME |awk '{print $2, $7}' |egrep -v "00:00:00" |awk '{print$1}')

sleep 1
for kill_process in $MY_PS; do
/bin/kill -9 $kill_process
done

# Verificamos que se ha realizado correctamente
VERIFY=$?
if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
    echo -n "Jar instance stopped correctly"
    echo -ne "\033[0;32m                     [OK] \033[0m"
    echo $" "
else
    echo -n "Jar instance stopped incorrectly"
    echo -ne "\033[0;31m                     [Error] \033[0m"
    echo ""
    echo "It is required to kill process "$MY_PS" manually."
    echo "Ask your administrator"
    echo $" "
fi

echo $" "
echo -n "Starting Jar"
echo $" "

nohup java -Dprops.dir=conf -jar func.jar &

echo $" "
echo -n "Jar running"
echo -ne "\033[0;32m                                            [OK] \033[0m"
echo $" "
;;
```

The problem I'm having is that when setting the *nohup ... &* in order to execute in background jar file is not doing anything. If I write:

```
java -Dprops.dir=conf -jar func.jar
```

Then it works. My jar file is using a quartz library (scheduler library for Java), I don't know if some of you knows if there is any incompatibility between nohup and quartz...

Or maybe there is somekind of problem with setting JVM variables (*-Dprops.dir=conf*)

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried both nohup and screen to keep a java app with Quartz running overnight with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, it turned out to not be related to Quartz at all.  I was using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() for some cheap asynchronous tasks.  For some reason the program was working only if I had xwindows running on my desktop, but would terminate with no error logged when I shut down my computer (also shutting down xwindows).  The fix was to start the program with -Djava.awt.headless=true